# Merge queries into one query

Tags: sql, mysql

I have the two following tables (with some sample datas)

LOGS:

```
 ID | SETID | DATE
========================
 1  |   1   | 2010-02-25
 2  |   2   | 2010-02-25
 3  |   1   | 2010-02-26
 4  |   2   | 2010-02-26
 5  |   1   | 2010-02-27
 6  |   2   | 2010-02-27
 7  |   1   | 2010-02-28
 8  |   2   | 2010-02-28
 9  |   1   | 2010-03-01
```

STATS:

```
 ID | OBJECTID | FREQUENCY | STARTID | ENDID
=============================================
 1  |    1     |   0.5     |    1    |   5
 2  |    2     |   0.6     |    1    |   5
 3  |    3     |   0.02    |    1    |   5
 4  |    4     |   0.6     |    2    |   6
 5  |    5     |   0.6     |    2    |   6
 6  |    6     |   0.4     |    2    |   6
 7  |    1     |   0.35    |    3    |   7
 8  |    2     |   0.6     |    3    |   7
 9  |    3     |   0.03    |    3    |   7
 10 |    4     |   0.6     |    4    |   8
 11 |    5     |   0.6     |    4    |   8
 7  |    1     |   0.45    |    5    |   9
 8  |    2     |   0.6     |    5    |   9
 9  |    3     |   0.02    |    5    |   9
```

Every day new logs are analyzed on different sets of objects and stored in table LOGS. 
Among other processes, some statistics are computed on the objects contained into these sets and the result are stored in table STATS. These statistic are computed through several logs (identified by the STARTID and ENDID columns).

So, what could be the SQL query that would give me the latest computed stats for all the objects with the corresponding log dates.
In the given example, the result rows would be:

```
OBJECTID | SETID | FREQUENCY |  STARTDATE | ENDDATE
======================================================
   1     |   1   |    0.45   | 2010-02-27 | 2010-03-01
   2     |   1   |    0.6    | 2010-02-27 | 2010-03-01
   3     |   1   |    0.02   | 2010-02-27 | 2010-03-01
   4     |   2   |    0.6    | 2010-02-26 | 2010-02-28
   5     |   2   |    0.6    | 2010-02-26 | 2010-02-28
```

So, the most recent stats for set 1 are computed with logs from feb 27 to march 1 whereas stats for set 2 are computed from feb 26 to feb 28.
object 6 is not in the results rows as there is no stat on it within the last period of time.

Last thing, I use MySQL.

Any Idea ?

Comment: +1 for a clearly formulated question with good sample data.

Comment: Is your 0.35 for object 4, 5 a typo ? (it should be 0.6 ?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this query fit to your question ?

```
SELECT objectid, l1.setid, frequency, l1.date as startdate, l2.date as enddate 
FROM `logs` l1
INNER JOIN `stats` s ON (s.startid=l1.id)
INNER JOIN `logs` l2 ON (l2.id=s.endid)
INNER JOIN
 (
   SELECT setid, MAX(date) as date
   FROM `logs` l
   INNER JOIN `stats` s ON (s.startid=l.id) 
   GROUP BY setid
 ) d ON (d.setid=l1.setid and d.date=l1.date)
ORDER BY objectid
```

Comment: This would not return a row for objectid 6, because there is no log with setid=1 for that object

Comment: It doesnt return objectid 6 what is requested

Comment: Question is more ambiguous than I thought :)  How would you explain the frequncy 0.35 for object 5 in the example results?

Comment: I have thought that was a typo since there is nothing with 0.35 for object 4 and 5

Comment: oups you're right there is a typo: one should have read 0.6. By the way thanks a lot for your answer Patrick, it seems it does exactly what I want !

Answer (score 1):

If there are no ties, you can use a filtering join.  For example:

```
select   stats.objectid
,        stats.frequency
,        startlog.setid
,        startlog.date
,        endlog.date
from     stats
join     logs startlog
on       startlog.id = stats.startid
join     logs endlog
on       endlog.id = stats.endid
join     (
         select   objectid, max(endlog.date) as maxenddate
         from     stats
         join     logs endlog
         on       endlog.id = stats.endid
         group by objectid
         ) filter
on       stats.objectid = filter.objectid
         and filter.maxenddate = endlog.date
order by stats.objectid
```

Your example results appear to be slightly off, for example there is no row for objectid 5 where the frequency equals 0.35.

Comment: You are returning objectid 6 what is not requested ;)
'object 6 is not in the results rows as there is no stat on it within the last period of time'